# RDLC Report: Apply Filter to Report

Tags: c#, winforms, report, rdlc

I have two parameters `dateFrom` and `dateTo` which I want to filter my report based on those values and show sum of `total` column of filtered rows in the report.

Currently when I use expression `=Sum([total])` it returns the sum of whole column in database and it doesn't applying date filter on expression.

**Question:**
How to apply sum of total between dates `dateFrom` and `dateTo` parameter like Something like this pseudo-code:

```
=Sum(Field!Total.Value) where date between dt_from to dt_to
```

Here is the code I use to load show report:

```
invoice_viewTableAdapter.Fill(this.db_posDataSetInvoice.invoice_view);
reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

Comment: Do you have any date associate with each records to compare with these to and from dates?

Comment: You can apply the filter on datasource of the report.

Comment: yes there is a date column. Filter is applying on the whole table but at the end i want to get sum of total of filtered report ? I returns the sum of whole dataset not filtered report ???

Comment: i am applying filter through parameter that user select and change any time. So i want parameter should also apply on [total] to get total of all sales @RezaAghaei

Comment: If you have a report form that hosts some controls (form parameters values) and a report viewer to show the report, you can simply apply parameters to the data source and refresh report.

Comment: I am considering that you have date field name like "CurrDate".
Try using this expression:  sum(IIf((Parameters!dt_from.Value <= Fields!CurrDate.Value) && (Parameters!dt_to.Value > Fields!CurrDate.Value),Fields!Total.Value,0))

Comment: @RezaAghaei So, can you please tell me how to apply filters on datasource. **invoice_viewTableAdapter.Fill(this.db_posDataSetInvoice.invoice_view);**

Comment: @HamzaZaidi Do you also have an `invoice_viewBindingSource`?

Comment: No there is only one line that i mentioned above after that there is just **reportViewer1.RefreshReport();**

Comment: i have both vales coming from text box in a function that is invoked when user press the button .. how to apply these two dt_from and dt_to on datasource ?

Comment: OK but if you take a look at designer, you will see a BindingSource. It it there?

Comment: Sorry but there is only `db_posDataSetInvoice`

Comment: If you created the report viewer using designer and assigned the report using designer, there will be a `DataSet` a `TableAdapter` and also a `BidnigSource`. If you open smart tag of your report viewer (small arrow at top right) and click on choose datasources, what do you see?

Comment: Yes i found it there is `invoice_viewBindingSource`

Comment: So I'll post an answer for you.

Comment: I will be very thankful to you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should apply the filter on the data source of your report, for example:

```
invoice_viewTableAdapter.Fill(this.db_posDataSetInvoice.invoice_view);
this.invoice_viewBindingSource.Filter = "Put your filter here";
reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

Supposing you have a `MyDateField` field and you have dateFrom and dateTo of type of `DateTime`.

This can be your date filter:

```
String.Format("MyDateField>= #{0:yyyy/MM/dd}# AND MyDateField<= #{1:yyyy/MM/dd}#"
              , dateFrom, dateTo);
```

you can find more information about about `BindingSource.Filter` expression syntax [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Solved: Thank you sooo much Mr. Reza .. I am very much thankful to you :)