# RDLC Find Value in DataTable

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, visual-studio, rdlc

I am attempting to build a report in Visual Studio 2015 using rdlc reporting. I want to be able to lookup a value in my DataTable and display those results on the report
Here is my DataTable:
[image: DataTable]

This is example data from SQL:
[image].

I need to display the Summary Field Value in a text box on Page 1 of the report where the "SummaryType" is = to "Family Summary". Additionally I need to display the "POST Summary" on a Subsequent page in a text box.

I have programmatically created a dataset in Visual Studio that store all the data that is needed for the report for a particular applicant in there own individual data table. Most are single rows such as Name, Address, City, etc.  My problem is when it comes to the Summary Table, there are multiple rows in the data table, but I only need to display a single row, various times throughout the report. For example, I need to Display only the "Family Summary" in the Family Section of the report and only the "POST Summary" in the POST Section of the report.

Is there a function/expression that I can call in RDLC, that will lookup a value (i.e. "Family Summary") in the Summary DataTable and display the results in my report?

EDIT:
As a workaround, in Visual Studio, I filtered my Summary DataTable for each Summary needed and then created a Variable in RDLC, and assigned that variable the value that needs to be displayed. If there is a better, more efficient (correct) way, please let me know.

My results look like this:
[image]

Comment: Pass filtered data to the report data source. For example if you use a `BindingSource` as data source of report, set `Filter` property of `BindingSource`.

Comment: Here you can see an example: [RDLC Report: Apply Filter to Report](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33994830/rdlc-report-apply-filter-to-report?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a function/expression that I can call, that will lookup a value in the DataTable...?

You can use the [DataTable.Select Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/det4aw50(v=vs.110).aspx) to find rows that match your criteria.

```
Dim matchedRows as DataRow() = myDT.Select("[SummaryType]='MySummaryType'")
If matchedRows.Length > 0 Then
' extract needed field
End If
```

Comment: You can use `yourDataTable.DefaultView.RowFilter` to filter rows. If you used `DataTable.Select` method, you should put a copy of the result rows in a table and use that table as `DataSource` of your report, otherwise the result is useless.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but the DataTable contains Several different summary types that will be used in the report later. This is about a 35 Page Report that will be generated. One summary type will be "MySummaryType" another may be "YourSummaryType", another may be "HerSummaryType", etc. All the Summary types are known (Static) but depending on its location in the report, this will be dependent on what Summary Type to be displayed. As an example, "MySummaryType" may be placed on page 3 and "YourSummaryType" may be placed on page 8.

Comment: @Talister, please make it clear in your question how you are using the lookup value in your report.  I assumed that you would be assigning the value to a "Report Parameter" and that parameter is used in an expression for a report TextBox.Value property.

Comment: @RezaAghaei, for a single value assigned to a report parameter as I interpreted the OP's need to perform a value lookup, the result is not useless.

Comment: @TnTinMn the Parameter is what I was looking for. That will work. In code behind I was able to place the value that I needed into a parameter and place it in the report. THANK YOU!!! I have been working on that for days.

Comment: @TnTinMn No problem, I reopened the post. But the post really needs some clarification. It seems the OP is looking for filtering and using a parameter as solution is really strange. But they confirmed that is worked.

Comment: @Talsiter It's unclear what you are asking. It's great that your problem is solved. But please make the question more clear to be more useful for future readers. Currently based on your description I believe you need filtering as I mentioned. Please describe a sample input and say what is desired output.