# How to filter RDLC Report by date using two datetimepickers and a button in Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, rdlc

I have created an RDLC report and inside the table adapter I've added a query and in the form that holds the report viewer I've added 2 datetimepickers and a button. Inside the button click event, I've added code to initialize the tableadapter and datatable.

I Used the same code to filter the report by a Shift and it worked using a textbox and a button, but I really need to filter the report by Date, Shift and Line. But I figured I'd start with the datetimepickers first. As you all can see from my code I don't even know how to build a query to include Date, Shift and Line.

This is the code inside the tableadapter query

```
SELECT        [DateTime], Inspector1, Inspector2, LineTech, Line, Shift, PartNumber, Ribbon1, Ribbon2, Ribbon3, RB1Scrap, RB2Scrap, RB3Scrap, RB4Scrap, RB5Scrap, RB6AScrap, RB6BScrap
FROM            ScrapRepairsEntry

WHERE DateTime between FromDate AND ToDate
```

This is the code inside the button click event

```
DsRibbonTableAdapters.ScrapRepairsEntryTableAdapter adapter = new DsRibbonTableAdapters.ScrapRepairsEntryTableAdapter();
      DsRibbon.ScrapRepairsEntryDataTable table = new DsRibbon.ScrapRepairsEntryDataTable();

      adapter.FillBy(table, dtpFrom.Text, dtpTo.Text);

      ReportDataSource MyNewDataSource = new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", (DataTable)table);
      this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
      this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(MyNewDataSource);
      this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
      this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

When I run the code, it throws an exception "No overload for method 'FillBy' takes 3 arguments". I've been searching Google and trying different things for days, but nothing works. I don't know what else to try.

Comment: [RDLC Report: Apply Filter to Report](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33994830/3110834)

Comment: Or you can add a parametrized query to the table adapter and load filtered data.

Comment: If you look at the queries contained in the TableAdapter, how many parameters are showing in your Fillby, GetDataBy() query? Also, you probably need to wrap DateTime in your WHERE clause just like you did in your Fields list.

Comment: Charles May - There are no parameters showing in my TableAdapter FillBy or GetDataBy query. I did wrap [DateTime] in my WHERE clause just like in my Fields list, but that didn't fix it. in the code I have inside the form that contains the report viewer in the button click event the FieldBy has red squiggly lines, I'm thinking it's because the FillBy and GetDataBy query in the TableAdapter is not showing any parameters. And that line is where the debbuger is point to when it throws the "No overload for method 'FillBy' takes 3 arguments" exception.

Comment: Try `WHERE [DateTime] BETWEEN ? AND ?` This should then give you a parameter set of `DateTime` and `DateTime1` which will take in your parameters in the `Adapter.Fillby()`

Comment: I tried changing WHERE [DateTime] BETWEEN ? AND ? and the adapter.Fill took in the parameters. However, at run time, the datetimepickers aren't filtering the data when I click on the button.

Comment: I got it to work. I was using dtpFrom.MinDate, dtpToMaxDate and I changed my code to dtpFrom.Value, dtpTo.Value and it worked. Thank you Charles May, for all your help.